# php get unique sub array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get a solution in PHP to get unique array based on sub array bases. Like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1227
        [1] => 146
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 39
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1227
        [1] => 146
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 39
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1228
        [1] => 146
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 39
    )
)
```

to

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1227
        [1] => 146
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 39
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1228
        [1] => 146
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 39
    )

)
```

I mean to say  `array[1]` should be removed as `array[0]` and `array[1]` are the same. I tried to use `array_unique` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I think this does exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: You both did not really read the OPs question, I'd say...

Comment: I believe he wants to remove duplicate sub-arrays from his array. The question i linked solved that, I believe

Comment: I search goold and stackoverflow but could found that solution... might be not using correct keywords.

Comment: How can I link this quesiton to Hless's answers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be done with [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) but you'll also need to use the `SORT_REGULAR` (PHP 5.2.9+) flag:

```
$array = array(
    array(1227, 146, 1, 39),
    array(1227, 146, 1, 39),
    array(1228, 146, 1, 39),
);
$array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1227
            [1] => 146
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 39
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1228
            [1] => 146
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 39
        )

)
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/51338)

For older versions of PHP, you could use the [solution](https://eval.in/51337) I linked to in the question's comments:

```
$array = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works, except PHP manual says "that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays". Use with caution.